# Numpy mean cannot get other axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

I have my numpy object as:

```
[array([1, 1, 1]) array([2, 2, 2])
 array([3, 3, 3]) array([4, 4, 4])
 array([5, 5, 5]) array([6, 6, 6])]
```

My goal is to get a list/array of averages in all sub arrays, i.e. get the list [1 2 3 4 5 6].

I am getting with both np.mean and np.average: [3.5 3.5 3.5] which is the average of all first, all second, all third elements.

I tried added an argument `axis=1`, but then I am getting the error:

```
    avg = a.mean(axis)
  File "---/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 138, in _mean
    rcount = _count_reduce_items(arr, axis)
  File "---/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 57, in _count_reduce_items
    items *= arr.shape[ax]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I tried casting my object to np.array but this made no difference.

As I commented, this is a minimal reproduce of my problem:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=object)
A[0][0] = np.append(A[0][0], np.array([1]))
A[0][1] = np.append(A[0][1], np.array([2]))
print(np.array(A[0,:]).mean())          # ok
print(np.array(A[0,:]).mean(axis=0))    # ok
np.array(A[0,:]).mean(axis=1)           # bad
```

Comment: `np.mean(l, axis=1)` returns the correct answer `array([1,2,3,4,5,6])` on numpy 1.21.2. You can also try `np.array(l).mean(axis=1)`.

Comment: again the same error

Comment: What exactly is your *numpy object*, what do you get with `type(l)`?

Comment: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` please check my comment on how to repordyce the error

Comment: As commented earlier, `np.array(list(A[0,:])).mean(axis=1)` should work for you.

Comment: the `list` made it! Before that I was getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to write `a.mean(axis=axis)`. Complete solution:

**Code**

```py
from numpy import array

a = array(
    [
        array([1, 1, 1]),
        array([2, 2, 2]),
        array([3, 3, 3]),
        array([4, 4, 4]),
        array([5, 5, 5]),
        array([6, 6, 6]),
    ]
)
axis = 1

print(a.mean(axis=axis))
```

**Output**

`[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]`

Comment: does not work, and my object does not have commas between the inner arrays

Comment: Wouldn't be correct syntax without the commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> obj = [np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 2, 2]),  np.array([3, 3, 3]), np.array([4, 4, 4]),  np.array([5, 5, 5]), np.array([6, 6, 6])]
>>> np.array(obj).mean(axis=1).tolist()
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

To get it as integers

```
>>> np.array(obj).mean(axis=1, dtype=np.int32).tolist()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In your case,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=object)
A[0] = np.array([1])
A[1] = np.array([2])
A.mean(axis=1).tolist()
```

output:
[1.0, 2.0]

Comment: same error as in the post; for simplicity I am only printing the result when testing, so conversion to list is not problematic

Comment: problem is already that there is no axis=1

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array from the original display - with some tweaks, produces a 2d array:

```
In [23]: array=np.array
    ...: alist = [array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2]),
    ...:  array([3, 3, 3]), array([4, 4, 4]),
    ...:  array([5, 5, 5]), array([6, 6, 6])]
In [24]: alist
Out[24]: 
[array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([2, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 3, 3]),
 array([4, 4, 4]),
 array([5, 5, 5]),
 array([6, 6, 6])]
In [25]: np.array(alist)
Out[25]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6]])
In [26]: np.array(alist).mean(axis=1)
Out[26]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

Making a 6 element object dtype array from that list

```
In [29]: A = np.zeros((6),object)
In [30]: A[:]=alist
In [31]: A
Out[31]: 
array([array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2]), array([3, 3, 3]),
       array([4, 4, 4]), array([5, 5, 5]), array([6, 6, 6])], dtype=object)
In [32]: A.shape
Out[32]: (6,)
In [33]: A.mean()
Out[33]: array([3, 3, 3])
In [35]: A.sum()
Out[35]: array([21, 21, 21])
```

What `mean` is doing is adding the 6 arrays together to get [35], and then dividing by 6 to get the mean (truncated to int).

To get the mean of the individual arrays, use a list comprehension:

```
In [36]: [a.mean() for a in A]
Out[36]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

or turn it into a 2d array:

```
In [37]: np.stack(A).mean(axis=1)
Out[37]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

Your initial array display is a bit ambiguous.  It looks a lot like a list of arrays, except it is missing the commas.  A `repr` print of the array will be clearer, more like my `Out[31]`.

```
In [38]: print(A)
[array([1, 1, 1]) array([2, 2, 2]) array([3, 3, 3]) array([4, 4, 4])
 array([5, 5, 5]) array([6, 6, 6])]
```

An object dtype array with shape (6,) is not the same as a numeric dtype array with shape (6,3).  Functions like `mean` and indexing do not "reach through" that object boundary.  `A` does not have an "other" axis; it has only one.